# Report Viewer didn't call sub Report method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, reportviewer, subreport

I use following code to generate a PDF report:

```
public partial class Report{   
 public void myMethode(DataTable DT){

        ReportViewer reportViewer1 = new ReportViewer();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Something" + ReportName + ".rdlc";
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DT));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubReportProcessing);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

   }
 private static void SubReportProcessing(object sender, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
   {
        //do something
   }

}
```

It's work fine for every main report but when it want to generate subreport it dosen't call `SubReportProcessing` method!!!

So can some one help me to find problem??

I am using `Dot Net 4.7.2` also I used this as web api and I use `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` version `12.0.0.0`

Comment: no suggestion?!

Answer (score 2):

I Use This Event For Call SubReports:

```
      // myMethode Function
        reportViewer.Reset();
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report Path";
        reportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += 
                                 LocalReportOnSubreportProcessing;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

   private void LocalReportOnSubreportProcessing(object sender, 
                                                 SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Following Code Is just a Sample 
            switch (e.ReportPath)
            {
                case "ExamResult1To3Scores":
                    {
                        var ranksReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource
                        {
                            Name = "ExamResult1To3",
                            Value = GetCandidatesExamResultGuidanceRequest
                        };
                        e.DataSources.Add(ranksReportDataSource);
                        break;
                    }

                case "ExamResult1To3Chart":
                    {
                        var levelRank = 
                            GetCandidatesRequest.First().Guidance1To3ChartData;

                        var chartReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource
                        {
                            Name = "ExamResult1To3Chart",
                            Value = levelRank
                        };
                        e.DataSources.Add(chartReportDataSource);
                        break;
                    }
                  }
```

I Hope That You will Be Benefited From The Code.

Comment: Thanks for response,but it shows this error :`'reportViewer1.Controls' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ScriptManagerNotFoundException'`, Be aware I dont use controller

Comment: I dont Undrestand why you have a error after edit your code.
Plaese review your code and also check your report Designer.
Why Function output Is Void? Action Response is Byte array(Byte[ ]) .

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you think it was useful.thanks

Comment: I think problem is because of don't using a Report Viewer controller! what do you think? is it necessary to using a controller for this?!!

Comment: In any Case, there must be a Controller and an Action to send the Result to the View Or Frontend.

Comment: If I do not want to display the result and just want to output the file as a file or any other way to deliver it to the user, do I still need controller?

Comment: Yes.You are  Using web api .then You Should Use Controller For Show/Send To User